# Google maps gpx export - save dialog in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, maps, export, savefiledialog

I'm working on a GoogleMaps project and want to offer the users to save the current route as a GPX-file. I haven't found any function or possibility to do that.

So I thought maybe to go through the mapoverview array and save the coordinates and data after that. (open file dialog with JavaScript)
Now I only have appended the data to a text area, but it slows down the page extremely.

I didn't find anything to offer the generated data to be able to download.
-> Store it in a variable?

I have read that JavaScript can't write to User File System. But I only want to offer the data to be downloaded or right click - save as.

Has anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The new google maps is a bit tricky when it comes to fishing out the GPS coordinates themselves.

A while back I wrote a web-app that accepts a link to Google Maps directions and converts it to a gpx file or JSON.

https://mapstogpx.com

Perhaps it will be of use.

Comment: How did you do it?